# How can I cancel my "Vote to Close" a question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Well, I voted to close a question mistakenly and then I found out that I should cancel my "Close" vote. But seems I can't find any options to cancel my vote.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is a [requested but rejected feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

However, votes do expire over time and as it requires 5 votes or moderator intervention to actually close a post, if the question doesn't need closing it won't happen.